# Do I HAVE TO sign up to third-party sites for rewarded video ads?

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I have successfully implemented AdMob's test ads for rewarded videos. However, I saw on other sites that we have to sign up to third-party sites to get rewarded videos, and we get paid by those sites directly. But I'm not so sure about that because AdMob's documentation on rewarded video ads (seemed to) mentioned nothing about third-party sites.

So do we have to sign up to third-party sites to get the real video ads? What will happen if I simply just replace the test-ad id with the real ad-unit id on AdMob, and do nothing else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about AdMob policies and requirements and not about programming as defined in the [help] guidelines. If you have questions about AdMob accounts and payments, contact them directly via the contact links on their pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently admob delivers rewarded ads so you do not have to get them from third-parties.